# Realm - Async Transaction Insertion Order

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm

I use for loop to saving in Realm. Insertion order is very important. With main thread everything is ok but I want to save that data in background threads. So using multiple threads is losing insertion order.

```
for (int index = 1; index < upperNumber; index++) {
          saveDB(index);
}

private void saveDB(final int index) {
            try {
              realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                  User user = bgRealm.createObject(User.class, index);
                  user.setName(String.valueOf(index) + " Name");
                  user.setAge(index);
                }
              }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override public void onSuccess() {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Transaction Success: " + index);
                }
              });
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Error during Transaction: " + e.getMessage());
            }
}
```

There is a Realm documentation about auto-increment id and insertion order but this is also not working with Async Transaction;
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-incrementing-ids

How i guarantee insertion order with Async Transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: You could always do the insertions in one transaction instead of N transactions, but I hope you know that Realm does not preserve insertion order after deletions.

Comment: Thanks, insertions in one transaction better idea but after deletions, i have a problem again right? if is it, what's your opinion about guarantee insertion order?

Comment: That you should specifically add a field called `position` or something like that, then use `findAllSorted()`/`findAllSortedAsync()`